# Is it OK to call Task.Run inside using statement?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

Code like this, I want to put most of the work in a Task.Run, but I am not sure if the using statement will still work as expected.

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Task.Run(() => 
    { 
         /* capture ms and process the stream */ 
    }
}  // Will ms will be disposed here automatically?
```

Thanks.

Comment: The real question is "can I elide `await` inside a `using` statement?" It really has nothing to do with `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 7):

No - The stream disposal may run before your Task has finished running. You'd be better off putting the using inside the Task if you can, or manually handling the disposal at the end of the Task.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
Task.Run(() =>
{
    /* capture ms and process the stream */

    // Dispose of the stream manually when you are done
    ms.Dispose();
}
```

Note that if you are using the memory stream outside of the Task, then you run the risk of using it after it is disposed. If you can, only use the stream inside the Task and save the results to somewhere else.

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        /* capture ms and process the stream */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think if I put an "await" ahead of Task.Run, that will make whole things work, correct?

Comment: Yep - @Letseatlunch has an example of that as well

Comment: It shouldn't matter if dispose is called twice

Answer (score 3):

The stream will most likely be closed and disposed of before the task has completed. This following throws a ObjectDisposedException:

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abc"),0,3))
{
    Task.Run(() => 
    { 
         Thread.Sleep(100);
         ms.Read(new byte[3], 0, 3);
    });
}
```

you could move the using statement into the task closure *or* you can await the task like:

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abc"),0,3))
{
    await Task.Run(() => 
    { 
         Thread.Sleep(100);
         var bytes = new byte[3];
         ms.Read(bytes, 0, 3);
         Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the two variations above, how about using `ContinueWith` to dispose? This is especially useful when you pass the task implementation as a delegate rather than implementing it inline:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
Task.Run(TaskUsingMemoryStream).ContinueWith(task => ms.Dispose());
```

You could argue, why would you create the memory stream outside the task if you are then immediately disposing of it once the task finishes but given that is what the OP is doing I assume there is some logic to this in their bigger picture. It think all answers have queried this choice.